# How to avoid standard include files during compilation

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to use my own printf function so i don't want to include standard include files... so I am compiling my code with `-nostdinc`

I have created my program something like this:

```
extern int printf(const char*,...);
printf("Value:%d",1234);
//printf("\n");
```

It is working fine for this code, but when I use `printf("\n")` then it is showing `undefined reference to 'putchar'`.

If i comment `printf("\n");` then `nm` command is showing

```
$ nm test1.o
         U exit
00000000 T main
         U printf
00000030 T _start
```

but if I use `printf("\n");` then `nm` command is showing

```
$nm test1.o
         U exit
00000000 T main
         U printf
         U putchar
0000003c T _start
```

I am not getting how and from where `putchar` is getting included

`gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)`

Comment: Why tagged C++? Why not just use a different name that `printf`?

Comment: It is replaced by the compiler thought good intentions.

Comment: I can use different name but I want to know the behavior of compiler.. why it is including `putchar` when i use `-nostdinc`

Comment: I am usng `-nostdlib` also at the time of linking then i am getting undefined reference to 'putchar'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gcc` optimizes `printf` in certain situations. You can look at the function `fold_builtin_printf` [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mirrors/gcc/master/gcc/builtins.c) for the complete details. IIRC, it optimizes calls with one argument followed by a newline to `puts/putchar`. You can turn it off by specifying `-fno-builtin`([gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html)).

Comment: Thanks Pradhan, It is working if i use `-fno-builting`.